# What is this tank?

Tags: gas, landscaping, underground, water-tank, spigot

There was a spigot that was randomly in our yard when we first moved in a couple months ago. Now that the weather is somewhat warmer, I decided to finally dig it up and find the source of water. While digging I found this random tank. Now my basement is finished and don't really want to open up holes in my walls under I know where the spigot somewhat is. There is also no indication of the spigot from inside the furnace/water tank room for the house which has exposed walls. I noticed that the water spigot goes underneath the tank so I'm not sure if it goes up and connects to the top or keeps going into the house. I can deal with that, I just don't know what the tank is. It looks to me like a gas tank for the house, but I don't have gas and see no other indication that I did. It could be just fill, but I'm not 100% sure. Does anybody have any other ideas on what this tank might be? I submitted a ticker in [Call Before you Did](https://www.cbyd.com/) before digging and the report came back with nothing in the yard, so this had to go unreported.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Call before you dig is a utility locate service, it  tells you if there are gas or electric utilities that need to be avoided so you do not kill yourself or blow up the neighborhood. In my neck of the woods One does not report things to the locate service, they come out, locate and mark.

Comment: Blue would usually indicate water. I wonder if it was a rain storage tank.

Comment: @AlaskaMan the utilities do report their infrastructure to the service, that is how they know which utilities to contact when you put in a call to have them marked. It is up to private utilities to report their presence in a given area. They can choose not to, but run the risk of having their stuff damaged. Source: I used to work for a municipal utility.

Comment: Could it be a pressure tank for a well?

Comment: @Duston My well is in the front of the house, while this tank is on the right side. Probably about 50ft from the well. The storage tank for the well is also in the house as well and there's no indication that it's connected to the well inlet to the house.

Comment: @isherwood I think it might be some type of storage tank. We accidentally broke the spigot pipe while digging and turned off the water from the house. The spigot did not loose pressure and kept flowing, so it might be connected to the tank. Just have to keep digging.

Comment: How deep is it and what climate are you in?   In the north. waterlines are usually at least 6 feet down so they don't freeze.

Comment: @SteveWellens It was only a few inches, maybe 6,  from the ground.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's an old pressure tank.  [Link](https://www.pentair.com/en/products/water-supply-pumps/pentair-pro-source-residential-products/pro-source_aw_steel_epoxylined_air-over-water_tank_series.html)  No idea why it would be sitting under your lawn, maybe the previous owners replaced it and decided to bury it if they had to pay to get rid of it.  Even if the tank itself isn't leaking, maybe there's a membrane inside that is.
Looks like the standing one second from the left.
[image: Looks like the standing one second from the left.]

Comment: Looks a lot taller than the second from the left. I'd say it's closer to the height of the tallest one (on the right)

Comment: "...and they never saw her husband again..."